# What exactly happend to the fbb-font in LateX when using the Ubuntu (13.10) installer

Tags: fonts, latex

I installed texlive-full from a repository instead of using the installer provided [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/). I noticed that the fbb font is missing, which seems to be specific to the Ubuntu packages?! I haven't found much on this on the web, including a way of properly obtaining/installing the font (I guess this is since the rest of the Internet doesn't have this problem using when the official installer). So

1. What happened to that font?
2. Besides using the official installer on my system, is there any other way to obtain the font?
3. If I would copy the font from another installation I did on another system using the official installer (e.g. copying all files named "fbb*" in the installation dir and updating the font system with updmaps)... would that work?

My specs:

```
Ubuntu 13.10     3.11.0-18-generic x86_64
texlive-full     2013.20130722-1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download the font from [This](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fbb) link and after that follow [This](http://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html) tutorial on how to install the font.

Just let me know when you need some more help.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sweet, that did the trick. Thank you. (For the record, I copied the font files to my $TEXMFHOME, which has a different directory structure. So there is a bit of manual work involved. After that an update with `updmap --enable Map=fbb.map` did the trick).

Comment: @Stormvirux thnx, sorry I will remember it for the next time

Comment: Batal: create a new answer detailing the steps you took to solve the issue and mark it as accepted.